# Radio Button List Selection and postback of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my program I have used upadate panel nad ScriptManager. My problem is,I am using radio button named RbFresh, It have two values named Fresher and Experienced when I select Experienced I will show a panel on this panel I have put text box control .But after selection any value in radionbutton  total page will be full postbacks.How will avoid full postback of my page.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>                                                
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbFresh" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="RbFresh_SelectedIndexChanged"                                                                    
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="297px" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Fresher" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Experienced" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
               </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>

 <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Rbfresh"/>                                      

</Triggers>
```

Comment: Remove `PostBackTriger`

Comment: Post that as answer.

Comment: I tried it.but didn't work without set postback trigger

Comment: What not working if you remove trigger?

Comment: What are you doing in `RbFresh_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: yes.but It didnt fire event

Comment: After removing `Trigger`, put breakpoint in `Page_Load` event and check if it is hitting or not

Comment: now fire Event ok .in this I call a panel to open that based on the value if it is Experienced . but Panel did not visible

Answer (score 0):

Using this code page will not be post back and you can easily get the value of radio buttons

Paste on HTML Page

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>                                                
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbFresh" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="RbFresh_SelectedIndexChanged"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="297px" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Fresher" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Experienced" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
               </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ContentTemplate>

     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

Paste on .cs Page

```
 protected void RbFresh_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Value = 0; int.TryParse( RbFresh.SelectedValue,out Value);
        int ID = Value;
    }
```